# Formula using VLOOKUP and ARRAYFORMULA returns parse error

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, vlookup

I am trying to get results from a 2nd tab by using 2 different drop down box's.

I for some reason can not get this to work properly, can someone please tell me what I might be doing wrong? I keep getting a Formula parse error and am not understanding it.

`=if($A2="XPO",ArrayFormula(vlookup($B2,'BBC Location'!$B2:$M,2,0(IF(A2="BBC",ARRAYFORMULA((VLOOKUP(($B2,'XPO Location'!B2:E96,2,0)))))))))`

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because it has a `0` immediately before a `(`.

```
                                                               |
                                                               v
=if($A2="XPO",ArrayFormula(vlookup($B2,'BBC Location'!$B2:$M,2,0(IF(A2="BBC",ARRAYFORMULA((VLOOKUP(($B2,'XPO Location'!B2:E96,2,0)))))))))
                                                               ^
                                                               |
```

Try this:

```
=ArrayFormula(
   if($A2="XPO", 
      vlookup($B2,'BBC Location'!$B2:$M,2,0), 
      IF(A2="BBC",VLOOKUP($B2,'XPO Location'!B2:E96,2,0))
    )
)
```

1. Usually a single ArrayFormula function is enough when it is included at the beginning of the formula.
2. It's possible to add line brakes and spaces to make the formula easier to read and review

Comment: Thank you, That did work. How can I add these together and still make them work correctly? =IFERROR(ArrayFormula(if($D2="bbc",vLOOKUP($G2,'Support Sheet'!$A$3:$D,{2,3,4},0)))) =IFERROR(ArrayFormula(if($D2="XPO",vLOOKUP($G2,'Support Sheet'!$A$3:$D,{2,3,4},0)))) =IFERROR(ArrayFormula(if($D2="bLLO",vLOOKUP($G2,'Support Sheet'!$F$3:$I,{2,3,4},0)))) =IFERROR(ArrayFormula(if($D2="ELVE",vLOOKUP($G2,'Support Sheet'!$K$3:$N,{2,3,4},0)))) =IFERROR(ArrayFormula(if($D2="TAYSOU",vLOOKUP($G2,'Support Sheet'!$P$3:$S,{2,3,4},0)))